# How to parallelly access files from shared location by 2 instances of a Springboot Service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, parallel-processing, instance, readfile

There are 2 instances of a spring boot service which read files coming to particular location. If a new file is added in the location then both the services read the file together. The aim is that the 2 instances should parallelly process the new files.

I have already tried the lock mechanism. It locks the file and one instance reads one file but the second instance does not read any new file till the lock is released.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow one of the simple options below.

1. *Keep a list of processed files*: The idea is to write the full path of the processed file in another file, database table or maybe even an in-memory space.
   The service which reads file first will first create an entry in that space. It's for marking the file. Other service looks up for the path of the file before it starts processing a newly created file. But it will fail to proceed since it's already there.
2. *Move the processed file*: Create a folder to archive the processed files. The service reads file first moves the file there and does the processing. Other service will fail to read that file. Btw, this option may not be viable if you are not allowed to move the file. In that case try to make a copy of the file.
3. *Copy the processed file*: Similar to the item#1. Make a copy of file in a folder. The service reads file first copies the file there and proceeds. Other service looks up for the name(or other identifier) of the file in that copy folder. It will fail to proceed since it's already there.

Many other variations can be produced, but the basic idea is to mark that file path so that it is already processed or in-progress.

Please note that, you have to rollback in case you cannot complete your processing on the file. Depending on the option you choose, you need to delete the record in the list or move back the file in the original directory or delete the copy of that file.